# How to POST with XML type and get answer as java.lang.String in camel?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to make some small message translator to inject new type of data into existing system. To do it, I translate the new XML into internal class, do the operation, and the result I want to return as String. When I deploy the answer as XML there was no problem, but currently I get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement but has value: 00 of type: java.lang.String on: Message: 00. Exchange[ID-60345-1455623194156-43-5][Message: 00]
```

I tried to replace produces type, outType, adjusting the Headers with setting the Content-Type to text/plain, but it doesent help. The original bindingMode was XML. My goal is to return simple string with POST method.

```
<restConfiguration component="netty4-http" 
                  bindingMode="auto" 
                  contextPath="/WebServices/rest"
                  enableCORS="true">
   <endpointProperty key="nettySharedHttpServer" value="#sharedNettyHttpServer"/> 
   <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="false"/>
</restConfiguration>

<!-- defines the rest services using the context-path /user -->
<rest path="/service" 
     consumes="application/xml" 
     produces="text/plain">
   <description>REST service</description>

   <post uri="/request" 
         type="org.company.generated.VmML" 
         outType="java.lang.String">

       <route>
            <to uri="bean:authenticationBean?method=checkAuthentication"/>
            <bean ref="messageTranslator" method="vmmlToEntry"/>
            <to uri="bean:Service?method=store"/>
            <bean ref="messageTranslator" method="returnEntryToStringReplay"/>
       </route>
   </post>           
</rest>
```

Comment: Does it work if you set `bindingMode="off"`? You'd have to do the JAXB un-marshaling yourself then, but nothing should interfere with you returning a plain string if that is what you want to do.

Comment: I didn't try to set off mode. I tried xml, xml_json, auto. Finally I removed this property and it started to work. I don't know why it overrides my settings for single rest definition.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get my example to work with bindingMode="auto", so I cannot verify whether this is really the issue, but this works for me:

```
<camelContext id="rest-test" allowUseOriginalMessage="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" streamCache="false">
    <dataFormats>
        <jaxb id="jaxb" prettyPrint="false" contextPath="my.domain.classes" />
    </dataFormats>

    <restConfiguration component="jetty" scheme="http" host="0.0.0.0" port="9001" contextPath="/string/conversion" bindingMode="off" />

    <rest path="/test" id="rest-string-conversion" produces="text/plain" consumes="application/xml">
        <post>
            <route>
                <camel:unmarshal ref="jaxb"/>
                <camel:transform>
                    <camel:simple>${body.eventId}</camel:simple>
                </camel:transform>
                <log message="Event ID: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="string-conversion-test" />
            </route>
        </post>
    </rest>
</camelContext>
```

The response is a string with just the event ID I extracted from the `Event` object I receive in the route. However, the `Content-Type` header of the response is wrongly set to application/xml instead of text/plain:

```
200 OK
Content-Type:  application/xml
[..]
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Server:  Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)

d9870180-257a-11e5-b345-feff819cdc9f
```

Possibly your response actually does contain a string but your client gets confused by the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: I have the answer type in my REST client always plain/text